# Use letters and numbers in numerate simultaneously

Tags: enumerate

I want to have in text enumerate with numbers and letters simultaneously:

---

```
а) Text №1
б) Text №2
в) Text №1
```

---

```
1) Text №1
2) Text №2
3) Text №3
```

---

It is desirable to use **cyrillic letters** for enumerate.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you mean by `simultaneously`? Do you mean that you want every enumerated list to be typeset *twice*, first with Cyrillic letters and second with Arabic numerals? Or do you mean that you want some lists to use the former and some the latter? What class are you using and how are you typesetting Cyrillic?

Comment: `\item[xxx]` usually produces an item with label `xxx` regardless of the list type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` and register the `\asbuk` representation of counters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{щ}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\asbuk*),ref=\asbuk*]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),ref=\alph*]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),ref=\arabic*]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's very nice solution. Thank you, I has bookmarked it. :)

Comment: @QueueOverflow Sorry for being so late!

Comment: It is never too late. It will be able to help me and other people in future. :)

Comment: @egreg Why we need to use ugly string `\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{щ}` ? In previous realization of `enumitem` it was no need in it

Comment: @sergiokapone Since I'm in charge of neither `babel-russian` and `enumitem`, I can't say why it is needed. It works with the current versions of the packages and if I remove it I get errors.